# What does 'it(line3)' refer to?

Tags: word-usage

What does ***it***(line3) refer to? Does it refer to ***the growth of academic disciplines and sub-disciplines*** or ***selecting and organizing what was worthy of keeping***?

> ***The growth of academic disciplines and sub-disciplines***, such as art
> history or palaeontology, and of particular figures such as the art
> critic, helped produce principles and practices for ***selecting and
> organizing what was worthy of keeping***, though ***it*** remained a
> struggle(Siegel 2000). Moreover, as museums and universities drew
> further apart toward the end of the nineteenth century, and as the
> idea of objects as a highly valued route to knowing the world went
> into decline, collecting began to lose its status as a worthy
> intellectual pursuit, especially in the sciences. The really
> interesting and important aspects of science were increasingly those
> invisible to the naked eye, and the classification of things collected
> no longer promised to produce cutting-edge(Conn 1998) knowledge. The
> term “butterfly collecting” could come to be used with the adjective
> “mere” to indicate a pursuit of secondary academic status.

[A Companion to Museum Studies](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=oQ8c6kRgH1IC&pg=PA87&lpg=PA87&dq=The%20growth%20of%20academic%20disciplines%20and%20sub-disciplines,%20such%20as%20art%20history%20or%20palaeontology,%20and%20of%20particular%20figures%20such%20as%20the%20art%20critic,%20helped%20produce%20principles%20and%20practices%20for%20selecting%20and%20organizing%20what%20was%20worthy%20of%20keeping,%20though%20it%20remained%20a%20struggle.%20Moreover,%20as%20museums%20and%20universities%20drew%20further%20apart%20toward%20the%20end%20of%20the%20nineteenth%20century,%20and%20as%20the%20idea%20of%20objects%20as%20a%20highly%20valued%20route%20to%20knowing%20the%20world%20went%20into%20decline,%20collecting%20began%20to%20lose%20its%20status%20as%20a%20worthy%20intellectual%20pursuit,%20especially%20in%20the%20sciences.%20The%20really%20interesting%20and%20important%20aspects%20of%20science%20were%20increasingly%20those%20invisible%20to%20the%20naked%20eye,%20and%20the%20classification%20of%20things%20collected%20no%20longer%20promised%20to%20produce%20cutting-edge%20knowledge.%20The%20term%20%E2%80%9Cbutterfly%20collecting%E2%80%9D%20could%20come%20to%20be%20used%20with%20the%20adjective%20%E2%80%9Cmere%E2%80%9D%20to%20indicate%20a%20pursuit%20of%20secondary%20academic%20status.&source=bl&ots=ih5R8QUFsa&sig=ACfU3U3iQDRCtWp3ElBtUkp5_M9c48gnpQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiX6OzTl4jxAhVRwosBHWJOB7QQ6AEwBHoECBAQAw#v=onepage&q=The%20growth%20of%20academic%20disciplines%20and%20sub-disciplines%2C%20such%20as%20art%20history%20or%20palaeontology%2C%20and%20of%20particular%20figures%20such%20as%20the%20art%20critic%2C%20helped%20produce%20principles%20and%20practices%20for%20selecting%20and%20organizing%20what%20was%20worthy%20of%20keeping%2C%20though%20it%20remained%20a%20struggle.%20Moreover%2C%20as%20museums%20and%20universities%20drew%20further%20apart%20toward%20the%20end%20of%20the%20nineteenth%20century%2C%20and%20as%20the%20idea%20of%20objects%20as%20a%20highly%20valued%20route%20to%20knowing%20the%20world%20went%20into%20decline%2C%20collecting%20began%20to%20lose%20its%20status%20as%20a%20worthy%20intellectual%20pursuit%2C%20especially%20in%20the%20sciences.%20The%20really%20interesting%20and%20important%20aspects%20of%20science%20were%20increasingly%20those%20invisible%20to%20the%20naked%20eye%2C%20and%20the%20classification%20of%20things%20collected%20no%20longer%20promised%20to%20produce%20cutting-edge%20knowledge.%20The%20term%20%E2%80%9Cbutterfly%20collecting%E2%80%9D%20could%20come%20to%20be%20used%20with%20the%20adjective%20%E2%80%9Cmere%E2%80%9D%20to%20indicate%20a%20pursuit%20of%20secondary%20academic%20status.&f=false)

Answer (score 1):

'It' refers to selecting and organizing.

Although there were now principles and practices to guide the process of selection and organization, it was still difficult.